# Using Teradata stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Teradata Studio 16.20.

There are two tables in the database, table 1 and table 2. I want to join some columns of these two tables considering a condition and get output into another, temporary table. All this has to be done in a stored procedure.

I know the the select statement for this problem:

```
select books.bookid,bookmetadetails.unitprice
 from books 
  join bookmetadetails on books.bookid=bookmetadetails.bookid 
   and 
    bookmetadetails.stockavailability=0;
```

but i don't know how to use this to create a stored procedure in Teradata.

thank you.

Comment: what exactly is a problem? create a sproc or Insert statement with joins or create temporary table?

Comment: Why does it have to be a stored proc?  Nothing you are describing requires a proc.

Comment: i know basics of sproc. But with that i couldn't implement this question in teradata.

Comment: @Andrew yes that's correct but i am trying to learn sproc using this

Comment: There's lots of documentation. Go through that. If you have a specific question/problem, come back and post a new question.